# How to listen for escape key in UITextField on MacCatalystApp?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, mac-catalyst

I'm working on a MacCatalyst app. I want to listen for escape key when user is editing a UITextField.

I can listen to return key by accepting UITextFieldDelegate with method

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
}
```

Also the method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       
}
```

gets trigger for both escape and return key, but I am not able to differentiate if its the escape key or return.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t seem to be possible with UIKit. I have tried using `UITextFieldDelegate`, `keyCommands`, and `pressesBegan`, but none of them will report the escape key.

But you can catch the escape key if you’re willing to hack your way into AppKit’s local event monitoring using [`NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents).

Calling “unavailable” AppKit APIs is pretty ugly, but thankfully **mmackh** on Github has already built [a working solution](https://github.com/mmackh/Catalyst-Helpers/blob/master/IPDFMacEventBus.m), which is what I’m using:

```
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    private var keyboardMonitor: IPDFMacEventBusMonitor?
    
    fileprivate func setupKeyboardMonitor() {
        let keyboardMonitor = IPDFMacEventBusMonitor(type: .keydown) { event in
            guard let event = event else { return nil }
            
            if event.isESC() {
                cancel()
                return nil 
            }
            return event 
        }
        IPDFMacEventBus.shared().add(keyboardMonitor)
        self.keyboardMonitor = keyboardMonitor
    }
    #endif
```

If you prefer Swift or want to roll your own solution, check out the very cool [Dynamic library](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic), which makes it easy to call “unavailable" AppKit APIs from your UIKit code.

Comment: Works like a charm. Don't forget to `IPDFMacEventBus.shared().removekeyboardMonitor)` at some point.